# How to test Eagle schematic design?

Tags: eaglecad

I am doing a project where I have to design a PCB. I am new in this field. I am using EAGLE PCB software.

About my project: I am working on a project where I have to measure the environments temperature. I am using TI's CC2541 Bluetooth soc, temp sensor TMP102, DC DC convertor, SOC debug flash TSW-105-02-S-Q and MURATA's Balun transformer. Whenever I put the battery in my PCB, the temp sensor reads the data and send it to my phone via Bluetooth. For this PCB design I am using Eagle software. I am new to this software and am working alone in this project.

[image: Schematic]

Until now I have the schematic design on software. I am attaching my PDF file here, so you can check the file and tell me if I am going in a right direction or not.

And also how to check the design if it is correct or not? I clicked on the error button, it is showing warnings only not an error.

Here is the link for the PDF file of the [TI sensor tag](http://www.ti.com/lit/df/swrr126/swrr126.pdf).

Comment: The curcuit around the regulator is a mess. What is it supposed to do?

Answer (score 2):

The only way you can really "test" circuits in Eagle is by using the ERC tool (Electronics Rules Check) which checks for shorts, misplaced connections, etc. You can find it at the bottom of the left-hand toolbar. What you really want is a simulator though, something like Multisim or LTSpice. I can't guarantee that either of those programs contain all the components you'll need though, so you'll have to mess around with it a bit.

I am seeing quite a few issues with the schematic so far, but the ERC tool should point them out to you.

Comment: thanks for your reply.......I tried ERC tool but it is showing the warning, No errors are there....can you please tell me what are the issues...since no one is there to help me....I willbe very much thankfull to you...

Comment: Well the first thing I see is that you have shorted one of the secondaries of the transformer. I don't believe it should be like that. Also as mentioned before, your regulator circuit is a mess. Where did you get the circuit for that? You are also drawing wires and ending them in a junction that is not connected to anything (I realize this is a notation thing, but it is not a good way to do it), and overall the circuit is just very sloppy and difficult to read/follow. I'm also not sure why you're mixing different ground symbols. Where did you get your reference diagram?

Comment: I am using the TI's reference diagram....like TI Sensor Tag......about the regulator its little bit messy..

Comment: could you link to the reference diagram please? Preferably in your original post

Comment: i added the link for for the PDF file of TI sensor diagram....